# Decimal value reading as null

Tags: vb.net, winforms, radgridview

I am using the RadGridView from Telerik for my winform application. In a particular cell I have 0 as decimal value. Within the `rowvalidation` event this value is read as undefined, though.

How can I check for that undefined value and get some value? Any immediate help will be appreciated. Please view the error screenshot for better understanding:

[image]

Comment: Where do you see undefined?  `0D` is a decimal 0.  0 is **not** null (Nothing). If you want to skip that cell on row validation then change your `If` statement to `If cell.Value = 0 Then`.  Note you may need to convert the type of `cell.Value` to decimal first.

Comment: Thanks for reply. Please see my critaria in code. I write if cell.value = nothing then ..... this should not accept decimal value like null and should skip reading decimal value. And I cannot use zero value in my criraria becoz greater than zero values effect from this critaria. Please tell me how can i skip reading decimal value as u can see in screenshot Thanks.

Comment: I'm not sure what you're trying to do - your code doesn't tell me anything about what your criteria is, beyond what I can see in your code (which checks to see if the cell is Nothing).  Can you try clarifying your criteria, and what it is you want to happen on row validation?

Answer (score 0):

You need to know the differences between:

1. [Value Types and Reference Types](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t63sy5hs.aspx).
2. [Is Operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kb136x1y%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) and [= Operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/41d8z008%28v=vs.90%29.aspx).

In this case one should not use the `=` operator but the `Is` operator.

```
If (cell.Value Is Nothing) Then
```

You can also test using the [TypeOf](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0ec5kw18.aspx) operator:

```
If (Not TypeOf cell.Value Is Decimal) Then
```